# Bezier Curve does not want to work with Array or Curve modifiers

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

So I've got a bezier curve and I want to use it to create a super simple road. The road object is literally just a plane. Whenever I add the array modifier to the road and set it to fit curve it only extended twice the length it was. When I add the curve modifier it rotates it slightly but nothing else. I'll attach the blender file (~900kb) so you can see exactly what I mean.
Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cxgDtm2K-N7xxrM9HdsopXwDzs1MIFWJ/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, that was a trickier one ;)

The problem with your curve(s) are: It's not just one part, they consist of two parts.

You can verify this by selecting the curve and press ".". Then you will see that the curve isn't really centered.
One easy way to fix it is: With your blend file opened, just add a cube, then press "." so that the view gets centered around the world origin. Then press x to delete the cube. Now you see there the rest of your splines.

[image]

Select it in object mode, go to edit mode and just delete the vertices (do these for the other curves as well).

Then it works.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this solved it, thanks Chris! Would have never figured that out on my own lol!

Comment: that's absolut normal. When i started Blender i was helped a lot and wouldn't have figured out it myself too.